# How to "see" all the traffic that leaves my network

Tags: proxy

Here is my setup:

Cable Modem >> ASA 5505 >>> LAN

I want to be able to see all the traffic that leaves the network such as what websites are being visited, IP connections made, etc.  I would like to see this in some sort of browseable report.  I am looking for the most efficient way to do this whether it be a logger/SIEM, new firewall, web proxy, etc.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: There are several things wrong with this "question": 1.) Product recommendations are off-topic. 2.) This question isn't about information security at all. 3.) This is not a question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide 2 demo scenarios with free/open-source apps.

1. You can use any sort of firewall or network monitoring tool to pass all your traffic through, make it keep logs and feed these logs to an elasticsearch/kibana. I have seen this combo doing fairly good job analyzing logs in blue team exercises with live attack/defence scenarios.
2. Use an external firewall/IDS/IPS and find/install an add-on that does this. I know that pfsense has "ntopng" and maybe more for that reason, but I can't say. I have experience over it.

Personally, I would suggest the first method because it could open many new ways of analyzing data for many different cases.

Comment: thanks for that info!  Would the URL's visited be part of those logs?

Comment: Depending on what you wish to log, yes.